# How parametrize generic singleton in java

Tags: java, generics, type-safety

I have next problem. I have an interface:

```
public interface Worker<T> {
    public void start(Class<? extends T> taskClass);
}
```

and singleton implementation of this interface:

```
public final class Listener<T extends Runnable> implements Worker<T> {
    private Listener() {}

    @Override
    public void start(Class<? extends T> taskClass) { ... }

    public static Listener getInstance() {
        return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
    }

    private static class SingletonHolder {
        public static final Listener INSTANCE = new Listener();
    }
}
```

My question is, can I get the singleton instance by this way:

```
Worker<Thread> listener = Listener.getInstance();
```

is still type-safe? when not, how can I use generic in singleton instance to by type-safe?

Comment: So the singleton isn't typed, do you want a typed singleton instance?

Answer (score 5):

All generics are stripped at runtime.

This means you're only going to have one `static class SingletonHolder` and only one `INSTANCE` no matter what the generic is.

To get past this, you could have 'multiple singletons' if that makes sense. You would have to add some kind of registration, so if you tried to get one that didn't exist yet, create and store it before returning it. Note this isn't compiled, and there may be some issues with it, but the basic approach is still the same.

```
public final class Listener<T extends Runnable> implements Worker<T> {
    private Listener() {}

    @Override
    public void start(Class<? extends T> taskClass) { ... }

    public static Listener getInstance(Class<T> clazz) {
        return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE.get(clazz);
    }

    private static class SingletonHolder {
        private static final Map<Class<? extends Runnable>,Listener<? extends Runnable> INSTANCE = new ...;
    }
}
```

Comment: `getInstance` might benefit from a definition like: `public static <V> Listener<V> getInstance(Class<V> clazz)`

Comment: The common name for 'multiple singletons' is multiton - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern.

Comment: @Mark yeah I like that. I really don't care for its current state of being "ungeneric".

Comment: @emory Very cool. I wasn't aware of that as I try to avoid singletons when I can anyway. But thanks for that info!

Comment: multiton is made up. wikipedia is supposed to record pre-existing knowledge. you can't just create a page on wikipedia to make your invention authoritive.

Comment: @irreputable It seems to be recording pre-existing knowledge. I have seen far worse cited Wikipedia articles than that.

Comment: But you cannot using parametrized type declared in class header in static attributes!

Comment: well, I'm sure the author had a pre-existing idea about the term before he wrote the wiki page. wikipedia also requires "notability" of the term.

Comment: @Pierre - indeed, use my method def'n above an you won't have trouble.

Comment: I think you should replace `getInstance(Class<T> clazz)` with `getInstance(Class<? extends Runnable> clazz)` as the method is static

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
public final class Listener implements Worker<Runnable> {
    private Listener() {}

    @Override
    public void start(Class<? extends Runnable> taskClass) { ... }

}
```

clearly, the listener instance can accept any Thread subclass.

```
Worker<Runnable> worker = Listener.getInstance();
worker.start( MyThread.class );
```

If you want to restrict the type, to clarify that the worker is for Thread subclasses, you can't

```
Worker<Thread> worker = Listener.getInstance(); // error[1]
```

but you can

```
Worker<? super Thread> worker = Listener.getInstance();
worker.start( MyThread.class ); // works for all Thread subclasses.
worker.start( SomeRunnable.class ); // error; only for Thread subclasses.
```

If we hate wildcards (we do), we may want to argue that clearly a `Worker<Runnable>` is also a `Worker<Thread>`; `error[1]` is just silly restriction.

One of the *benefit* of erasure is that, we can establish this kind of covariance.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Worker<Thread> worker = (Worker<Thread>)(Worker) Listener.getInstance();
```

We know the cast is safe for all intents and purposes.

If this is needed frequently, we can move the covariance casting to `getInstance()` for easy use:

```
Worker<Thread> worker = Listener.getInstance();

public final class Listener implements Worker<Runnable> 

    static Listener instance = new Listener();

    // it is safe to cast Worker<A> to any Worker<B>
    // as long as B is subtype of A

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

    static public <T extends Runnable> Worker<T> getInstance()

        return (Worker<T>)(Worker)instance;
```

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, but your code isn't clean according to http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf at page 14, chapter 7.2